# can you push 2 of the same UIViewController on the UINavigation stack?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have an app where I want unlimited categories and sub-categories and would only like a single UIViewController be used to display the categories and just keep adding instances of it to the UINavigationController - is this an allowed practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that, but i wonder why you would want to push multiple instances of same Controller's view onto stack. I hope each view is different from previous. In that case your requirement should be the user can come back to previous state of the view using the navigation controls.

Comment: each new instance has a different set of data, it is just a list of categories, like a drill down list

Comment: Then there is no reason why you cant do that. Plus i suppose you want to have back navigation as well